# PROOF: A Relationship Between A Natural Number and The Quantity of Its Divisors' Divisors

Tags: summation, proof-explanation, prime-factorization, natural-numbers, divisor-sum

An arbitrary natural number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ has the divisors $d_1,d_2,...,d_s$ , where $N$ has $s$ divisors in total. If $n_i$ denotes the number of dividers to $d_i, i = 1, ..., s$, it can be proven that

$n_1^{3}+n_2^{3}+n_3^{3}+...+n_s^{3} = (n_1+n_2+n_3+...++n_s)^2$

For example, let $N=6$. $N$ has the divisors $1,2,3,6$ which has the number divisors $1,2,2,4$ respectively. It follows that

$1^3 + 2^3 + 2^3 +4^3 = (1+2+2+4)^2$

stating that

$LHS=RHS$.

Using the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, a pattern emerges. Let $P_i\in \mathbb{P}$, $k_i \in \mathbb{N}$. It follows that any natural number can be written as

$N = P_1^{k_1}\cdot P_2^{k_2}\cdot P_3^{k_3}\cdot ... \cdot P_s^{ks}$.

Using this property, the pattern noted suggests that the greatest divisor's number of divisors can be formulated as

$N = P_1^{k_1}\cdot P_2^{k_2}\cdot P_3^{k_3}\cdot ... \cdot P_s^{ks} \iff n_s=(k_1 +1)(k_2 +1)(k_3 +1)...(k_s +1)$.

This is my progress so far. Any help towards solving this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. I, like lulu, am also not clear on what you're asking. It seems, however, you're suggesting the number of divisors is determined by your last line's $n_s=(k_1 +1)(k_2 +1)(k_3 +1)...(k_s +1)$ expression. Note this is quite well known, such as shown near the end of Wikipedia's [Formulas at prime powers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function#Formulas_at_prime_powers) section of "Divisor function" where it states $\sigma _{0}(n)=\prod _{i=1}^{r}(a_{i}+1)$.